# Why is there a weird white rectangle in the left corner of my window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

For some reason there is a weird white rectangle in the upper left corner of my screen. I was also try to draw a square on the JPanel and it does not seem to be working. I should also probably mention that I am just beginning to learn about Jframes and Jpanels (although I have made a few simple apps) so the code you see bellow might not be very clean:

**Main**

```
import javax.swing.*; 


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] agrs) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Space Ship"); 

    new GameFrame(frame);
    new GameGraphics();
   }
}
```

**GameFrame**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameFrame {

    GameGraphics game; 

    GameFrame(JFrame frame) {
        game = new GameGraphics(); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

**GameGraphics**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 

public class GameGraphics extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    
    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = SCREEN_WIDTH * 9 / 16;
    static final Dimension SCREEN = new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT); 
    Player player; 
    int playerHeight = 25;
    int playerWidth = 25;
    int playerX = (SCREEN_WIDTH/2) - 200;  
    int playerY = SCREEN_HEIGHT/2; 

    GameGraphics() {
        this.setPreferredSize(SCREEN);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void start() {}

    public void newPlayer() {
        player = new Player(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
    }

    public void newFireball() {}

    public void collisons() {}

    public void gameOver() {}

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); 
        draw(g); 
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        player.draw(g);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {}
}
```

**Player**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 

public class Player extends Rectangle {
    int x = 200; 
    int y = 200; 

    Player(int playerX, int playerY, int playerWidth, int playerHeight) {
        super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is one of the few times that I would suggest pasting in an image of your screen, showing this weird rectangle.

Comment: Agreed with @NomadMaker: Screenshots are actively desirable _when asking about graphics output_.

Comment: Please show an Image or at least a link to an image so we can see your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you comments in time and my problem is already fixed. If I ask anymore graphical questions I'll be sure to post a screenshot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the point of the `new GameGraphics()` statement in your main method?

It is not needed and should not be there. Get rid of it.

```
Player(int playerX, int playerY, int playerWidth, int playerHeight) {
    super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
}
```

What is the point of the above code? You pass in parameters in the constructor, but then you never use the parameters.

Your code only compiles because the Rectangle class has those 4 field, but they would have default values (not the values you expect), which would probably cause your painting problems.

Don't extend Rectangle! You are not adding any new functionality to the Rectangle class.

Your `Player` class does not need to extend any class. Instead your `Player` class should look something like:

```
public class Player {
    int playerX; 
    int playerY; 
    int playerWidth;
    int playerHeight;

    Player(int playerX, int playerY, int playerWidth, int playerHeight) {
        this.playerX = playerX;
        this.playerY = playerY;
        this.playerWidth = playerWidth;
        this.playerHeight = playerHeight;

    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
    }
}
```

As noted by sorifiend, you are also not creating an instance of your Player object.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a `NullPointerException` because `player` is never defined in the `GameGraphics` class, and it is causing a glitch with your graphics:

```
Player player;
```

It looks like you have created a method to setup the player, but it never gets called:

```
public void newPlayer() {
    player = new Player(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
}
```

One solution could be to call the `newPlayer()` method in your `GameGraphics()` constructor:

```
GameGraphics() {
    this.setPreferredSize(SCREEN);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    //add it here
    newPlayer();
}
```

Or you can create the player like this:

```
public class GameGraphics extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    //...
    Player player = new Player(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
    //...
```

Once that is fixed it should no longer cause issue.